# Parsing looping through json array in swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

this is my php file from a server:

```
<?php

    $results = Array(
        Array(
            "name"      => "William",
            "location"  => "UK",
            "action"    => "Post Update"
        ),
        Array(
            "name"      => "Sammy",
            "location"  => "US",
            "action"    => "posted news"
        )
    );

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

And this is how I try to fetch the json array from within swift

```
let urlPath = "http://someurltophpserver"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                println("Error")
            } else {
                let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                // do something with the data
            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

The app crashes in this line `let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary` with error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x8c9b58) to 'NSDictionary' (0x8c9d74).
```

New to swift and http request, so not entirely sure what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your app is crashing is because of the `as!`. You’re trying to force unwrap an optional, so if this fails during run time, the app will crash.

Change the line to this:

```
if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
{
    // Do stuff if jsonResult set with a value of type NSDictionary
}
```

This will stop the app crashing, but by the looks of it the top level object returned by the JSON serialiser is going to be an `NSArray` not an `NSDictionary` you seem to expecting, that’s probably why the app is *actually* crashing.
You’re code says to the compiler “let jsonResult equal a value that is definitely going to be an NSDictionary”.

Also, as a side, I would recommend the easiest way to download some data is with `NSData(contentsOfURL:url)`. Run this in a background queue using Grand Central Dispatch to avoid blocking the main thread (UI).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

    // Run any other code on the main queue. Especially any UIKit method.

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({

        // Do stuff with data
    })
}
```